# How to add a name to a data frame and change a specific cell in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Here is a sample of my data:

```html
    class   gender
Yellow  12  F
Blue    14  M
red 13  F
```

I want to add a name for colours and then change "red" to "purple"

So I will get the following table:

```html
Colour  class   gender
Yellow  12  F
Blue    14  M
Purple  13  F
```

I have used the following codes

```html
setNames(cbind(rownames(df), df), 
          c("colour"))
```

But, it does not work. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this base R option works for you

```
cbind(
  Color = gsub("^red$", "Purple", row.names(df)),
  df, 
  row.names = NULL
)
```

which gives

```
   Color class gender
1 Yellow    12      F
2   Blue    14      M
3 Purple    13      F
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(class = c(12L, 14L, 13L), gender = c("F", "M", 
"F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Yellow", "Blue",
"red"))
```

Comment: @akrun Yes I saw it right now. That's weird upvote for OP's comments

Answer (score 2):

We create a column with `rownames_to_column` and `replace` the 'red' values in 'Colour' column to "Purple"

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   rownames_to_column("Colour") %>%
   mutate(Colour = replace(Colour, Colour == "red", "Purple"))
```

-output

```
df1
#  Colour class gender
#1 Yellow    12      F
#2   Blue    14      M
#3 Purple    13      F
```

---

`setNames` in OP's post, requires the "Colour" along with the column names of the 'df'

```
setNames(cbind(rownames(df), df), 
      c("Colour", names(df)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(class = c(12L, 14L, 13L), gender = c("F", "M", 
"F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Yellow", "Blue", 
"red"))
```

Comment: SetNames  does not change the colour ( so not interesting, sorry); dplyr add the name, but does not change the colour

Comment: @user330 I added the output I am getting which is same as your expected output

Comment: @user330 I am not following your comment about the `dplyr` solution.  Can you clarify as I get the expected output

Comment: Thanks, yes, but in my original sample it does not change the colour,

Comment: @user330 Just change the assignment to your original object (updated)

Comment: @user330 You meant this is not possible `df1 <- df1 %>%
   rownames_to_column("Colour") %>%
   mutate(Colour = replace(Colour, Colour == "red", "Purple"))` ?

Comment: @user330 I am not following your comments.  It is the standard way of modifying an object

Comment: Thanks to both of you for taking the time. I have upvoted both, but I like basic R codes and  @ akrun, I am really sorry.

Comment: @user330 thank you.  It is a pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, a data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)  # tranform df into a data.table a change the row names into a column called rn
setnames(df, "rn", "Color")  # change the name
df[Color=='red', Color:="purple"] # change "red" to "purple"
df
```

Comment: Note that you can simplify both `setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)` and `setnames(df, "rn", "Color")` to `setDT(df, keep.rownames = "Color")`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option :

```
#add rowname as new column
df$Colour <- rownames(df)
#remove rowname
rownames(df) <- NULL
#replace 'red' with 'Purple'
df$Colour[df$Colour == 'red'] <- 'Purple'
df

#  class gender Colour
#1    12      F Yellow
#2    14      M   Blue
#3    13      F Purple
```